# Why the same curl request to the Soundcloud API with the same client id works on my local network but not on my server?

Tags: curl, soundcloud

I use the Soundcloud API for a while on my local computer and it works great but I don't manage to make it work on my remote server.

Here is the problem, if I do, on my computer:

```
curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3207?client_id=2a37f8098705604b8679fd079d5ad87u"
```

I get the expected result. **If I run exactly the same query on my remote server, I get a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code.**

Please note that I added the address IP of my server on my Soundcloud account.

I don't have any idea what can be done in order to make it work or even to debug it...

Comment: To debug it, add `-v` switch with your curl. I'd recommend you to use `-v` for both local and server commands and then compare the `request header` from both.

Comment: Your curl does give me a 401 Unauthorized response on my remote server. I switched your client_id with mine and it worked fine though. Start there.

Comment: I changed the client id that I pasted here in order not to let it be used by SO readers.